# Sampling from a very high dimensional Gaussian with covariance in block form

Tags: statistics, random-sampling, spatial-data, gaussian-process

I'm interested in sampling from a Gaussian with zero-mean and covariance given by:
$$
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \cdots &\Sigma_{1,100}\\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \cdots &\Sigma_{2,100}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots &\vdots \\
\Sigma_{100,1} & \Sigma_{100,2} & \cdots &\Sigma_{100,100}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\Sigma_{ij}$ is a square matrix of dimension $p \times p$. In words, the covariance matrix is massive and I am not able to load the entire array into memory. Are there any approaches that allow me to sample from such a Gaussian but only access a subset of the blocks at a time?

More background: The covariance matrix of interest is the Gram matrix with each element equal to $k(x,y)$ for a positive definite kernel $k$. The grid of points is a very fine discretization of the unit cube $[0,1]^2$ (1000x1000), so the Gram matrix is dimension 1Mx1M. The only way I've been able to calculate this is to compute individual blocks and store them on my harddrive, as opposed to keeping everything in memory. I'm stuck though with actually sampling from this distribution. If there are alternative approaches to this problem that would also be welcome, though I do not want to consider less fine partitions of the unit cube.

Comment: Do you have any estimation of the distribution of singular values of the blocks? For kernels like this, is is often the case that blocks further from the diagonal can be approximated via a low-rank matrix like the thin SVD.